# PostgreSQLの PL/pgSQLの条件分岐で行き詰ってます。

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL の PL/pgSQL
A5：SQL Mk2 x64 を使用しています。
Windows 11です。

以下のようなお菓子を分類する関数を作っていますが、エラーが出てしまいます。

IFで書いてみたり、CASE文の書き方を変えてみたりしましたが、うまくいきません。
何が悪いのかわかりません。
すいませんが教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

エラーメッセージ:

```
´やきもの系’もしくはその周辺で構文エラー
```

SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.okashi_bunrui(okashi character varying)
 RETURNS character varying
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

BEGIN 
    CASE
        WHEN okashi IN ('crackers','せんべい','senbei') THEN 'やきもの系';
        
        WHEN okashi IN ('飴','アメ','candy','キャンディ') THEN 'アメ系';
        
        WHEN okashi IN ('チョコ','チョコレート','chocolate') THEN 'チョコ系';
        
        ELSE;

    END CASE;
END;
$function$
```

Comment: このコードそのままであれば、テーブルにしてそれを検索するほうがよいです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。元の大きいテーブルがあって、その中の商品を分類するためのplpgsqlなんですが、どの部分をテーブルにして検索するのがいいとおっしゃっているのでしょうか？　もしよろしかったら教えてください

Comment: `okashi`を検索して対応する`bunrui`を取得するというのは`SELECT bunrui FROM tbl WHERE okashi=?`というごく基本的な検索でできることなので、どの部分というか、全体が不要な処理です。すでにあるテーブルの`okashi`に対して`bunrui`を紐付けたい(紐付けた結果がほしい)ならJOINすればよいです。トリガとして使いたいなどどうしてもストアドプロシージャにする必要があるにしても、テーブルを検索して値を返す形にした方がよいです。

Comment: なるほど。joinで紐づけるだけで取得することもできるんですね。おしえてくださってありがとうございます。次の機会にやってみます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

文字列や数値を直接戻す場合は`THEN`の後ろの`;`が不要です。(`THEN 'やきもの系'`や`THEN 0`など)
また`ELSE`を記述した場合は、`ELSE NULL`のように戻す値を指定してください。
※`:=`で変数への代入を直接行う命令文を記述する場合は`THEN`の後ろに`;`が必要です。(`THEN bunrui := 'やきもの系';`など)

蛇足ですがCASE文を書いても値を変数などに代入しないと意味がありません。
代入後の変数を末尾で`return`するコーディングが関数の基本的な使い方です。
下記のサンプルコードは`CASE`文を使って3種類の方法で`bunrui`変数に値を代入する例です。

**サンプルコード**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.okashi_bunrui(okashi character varying)
 RETURNS character varying
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare 
    bunrui character varying(20);
begin

    -- SELECT INTOで代入
    select
    CASE 
        WHEN okashi IN ('crackers','せんべい','senbei') THEN 'やきもの系'
        WHEN okashi IN ('飴','アメ','candy','キャンディ') THEN 'アメ系'
        WHEN okashi IN ('チョコ','チョコレート','chocolate') THEN 'チョコ系'
        -- ELSE NULL -- 省略可
    END
    into bunrui;

    -- CASE文の戻り値を代入
    bunrui := CASE 
                  WHEN okashi in ('crackers','せんべい','senbei') THEN 'やきもの系'
                  WHEN okashi IN ('飴','アメ','candy','キャンディ') THEN 'アメ系'
                  WHEN okashi IN ('チョコ','チョコレート','chocolate') THEN 'チョコ系'
                  ELSE '該当なし'
              END CASE;

    -- CASE文の中で代入
    CASE 
        WHEN okashi in ('crackers','せんべい','senbei') THEN bunrui := 'やきもの系';
        WHEN okashi IN ('飴','アメ','candy','キャンディ') THEN bunrui := 'アメ系';
        WHEN okashi IN ('チョコ','チョコレート','chocolate') THEN bunrui := 'チョコ系';
        ELSE bunrui := null;
    END CASE;

    RETURN bunrui;
END;
$function$;
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。書いていただいたことの大部分が、情けないことに知らないことばかりでした。”蛇足ですが”と書いてくださったことも、書いていただかなかったらわかりませんでした。サンプルコードとして書いていただいた3つめの書き方を使ってうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。助かりました。